# Assign class to href using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, redirect, fancybox

```
function loadRedirect(){
 var pageLoadRequest = '/marketing/choose-your-country';
 var classAssign = document.getElementsByClassName("fancyBox");
 setTimeout(function(){window.location.href=pageLoadRequest;},20);
}
```

I have this function inside script tags on a page of my website and I want it to open a fancybox popup by redirecting it to a URL with a class of fancyBox.  I thought maybe getting the class of the link on the page and then adding it to the above URL but I'm not sure how to do that.

I'd appreciate any help at all. 
Thanks!

Comment: It wouldn't be easier just to open the url directly from a link with class fancybox? Anyways, you can set the `href` form a function into your class like http://jsfiddle.net/R8cZ9/

Comment: BTW, fancybox is a jQuery plugin so you can skip that part